# add square brackets in each line of the file using bash

Tags: bash, sed, brackets, square-bracket

I would like to add square brackets to each and every line of my file.

I was using `sed -i "s/\(.*\)/[\1]/" file_name.txt` command but I see that it is inserting 2 times the square brackets and my output (just the first line and it's the same for every single line) looks like this

```
[[1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,24,3,0,0,0,0,86,149,149,14,0,0,0,0,32,149,46,16,0,0,1,13,3,33,65,66,0,0,0,0,0,2,149,140,6,0,0,2,62,148,88,24,26,2,0,14,116,148,30,15,1,0,0,1,5,30,56,18,0,0,0,0,0,4,149,46,40,14,0,0,1,34,31,46,149,31,0,2,9,12,1,7,8,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,12,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

How do I insert just one single square bracket for each line using sed? Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your sed command works fine for me.

Comment: I tried piping some text through your sed command like `echo foo | sed "s/\(.*\)/[\1]/"` and got `[foo]`. Is it possible you ran the command twice? If not: which version of `sed` are you using?

Comment: It was working fine for me as well. I don't know what went wrong :(

Comment: Do you know that `-i` flag edits file in place and if you run the command multiple times on same file, it will keep on adding the square brackets?

Comment: @Amit Yes. But the first time I run it, it is not saving the file with the square brace and when I run it again I get 2 square brackets. I am not understanding why the file is not displaying the single brackets when I run it once :/

Comment: @DanielBöhmer Yeah. For piping it is working but not when I run it in my file :/

Comment: I even tried it with a file and it worked like expected. How do you call `sed`? Is this part of a larger code? I still suspect it's called twice. Did you double-check there are no square brackets before?

Comment: Yes, I double checked it. I deleted that file and again created a new file and ran it and now it worked. I did the same like 10 times before (creating new file) and it didn't work then. It is weird

Comment: Off-topic: You can achieve the same effect with less typing: `sed 's/.*/[&]/'`. `&` in a replacement string represents the entire match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{print "["$0"]"}' file_name.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

your command is fine and should not add 2 `[` unless runnning twice. Also group, in this case, in not necessary, taking the whole pattern `&` is suffisant

```
sed -i 's/.*/[&]/' file_name.txt
```

Maybe, try with a single quote your own, double could aways be interpretated by something else from the shell